# Blacklist / Whitelist Table Design

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a set of users

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `unique_email` (`email`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

Each user can have one or many domains, such as

```
CREATE TABLE `domains` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `user_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
   `domain` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `domain` (`domain`),
   CONSTRAINT `domains_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

And we have a table that has some sort of data, for this example it doesn't really matter what it contains

```
CREATE TABLE `some_data` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `content` TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

We want certain elements of `some_data` to be accessible to only certain `users` or only certain `domains` (whitelist case).
In other cases we want elements of `some_data` to be accessible to everyone BUT certain `users` or certain `domains` (blacklist case).
Ideally we would like to retrieve the list of domains that the given element of `some_data` is accessible to in a single query and ideally do the reverse (list all the data the given domain has access to)

Our approach so far is a single table

```
CREATE TABLE `access_rules` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `rule_type` enum('blacklist','whitelist')
   `some_data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `domain_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `access_rules_some_data_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`some_data_id`) REFERENCES `some_data` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
```

The problem however is the fact that we need to query the db twice (to figure out if the given data entry is operating a blacklist or a whitelist [whitelist has higher priority]). (EDIT: it can be done in a single query)
Also since the domain_id is nullable (to allow blacklisting / whitelisting an entire user) joining is not easy

The API that will use this schema is currently hit 4-5k times per second so performance matters.
The `users` table is relatively small (50k+ rows) and the `domains` table is about 1.5 million entries. `some_data` is also relatively small (sub 100k rows)

EDIT: the question is more around semantics and best practices. With the above structure I'm confident we can make it work, but the schema "feels wrong" and I'm wondering if there is better way

Comment: Why twice? If whitelist is higher priority why not order the results by `rule_type DESC` and take the first? As for performance, it makes sense to me to cache this kind of thing especially if a user repeatedly interacts with a domain. If a user is whitelisted you can find that out at the start of their session and turn off checking for them

Comment: It sounds like you already know that whitelist and blacklist should be separate tables. On the other hand, I don't understand though why you need to do two queries-would not one query fore each data id be enough to fetch both white and blacklist?

Comment: @CaiusJard / Adder you are right, it can be done in one query. my bad
Semantically it would make sense for me to have two separate tables for blacklist / whitelist in which case however it would definitely be two queries

Comment: Can you provide a usercase with example data? And what the results should be with some filters.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: *"The API that will use this schema is currently hit 4-5k times per second so performance matters. "* MySQL community will not handle this scale that's like `0,00025‬` second to handle a result for 4K ... parsing a simple `SELECT 1` can already take up to `0.0001` in some cases -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/842 ... When needed join's the parsing / optimisation / permission checks / opening tables time  to start up per query will only increase

Comment: @RaymondNijland the API is of course distributed and the mysql db is replicated to multiple boxes

Comment: Ok that sounds good just wanted to give a heads up you know *"mysql db is replicated to multiple boxes "* By [MySQL cluster](https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/) ? i hope and assume ?   As that is only the "real" possible way to getting that [performance](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/benchmarks/mysql-cluster/) with ease..

Comment: *"EDIT: the question is more around semantics and best practices. With the above structure I'm confident we can make it work, but the schema "feels wrong" and I'm wondering if there is better way"*  Can you add in some example data and results based on some filters/examples (like requested before), that way we have a beter feeling for your usercase and we might be able to suggest something better if this current schema is indeed "wrong"..

Comment: @lePunk not necessarily - a UNION query can address multiple tables in a single hit

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to consider, normalization and management.
To normalize traditionally you would need 4 tables.

Set up the 3 master tables USER, DOMAIN, OtherDATA.

Set up a child table with User_Id, Domain_Id, OtherDATA_Id, PermissionLevel

This provides the least amount of repeated data. It also makes the management possible at the user-domain level easier.  You could also add a default whitelist/blacklist field at the user and domain tables.  This way a script could auto populate the child table and then a manager could just go in and adjust the one value needed.

If you have a two different tables, one for white and one black list, you could get a user or domain  on both lists by accident. Actually it would be 4 tables, 2 for users and 2 for domain.  Management would be more complex.